# ESLint error: 'value' is never reassigned use 'const' instead

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm adding ESLint to my Node project and cannot figure out how to change this code to work properly:

```
const connection = {};

for (let [prop, value] of connectionString) {
  prop = prop.split(' ')[0];
  connection[prop] = value;
}
```

I'm getting error:

`'value' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than reassigning `prop`, create a new variable for the first word. That way, both `prop` and `value` can be declared with `const`:

```
const connection = {};
for (const [prop, value] of connectionString) {
  const firstWord = prop.split(' ')[0];
  connection[firstWord] = value;
}
```

Most of the time, clean readable code can work just fine without ever reassigning a variable. Best to only reassign an existing variable when you *absolutely have* to - that's a big part of why the rule exists, to prod you to use `const` (and produce more readable code as a result).

You could also achieve it without the intermediate variable:

```
const connection = {};
for (const [prop, value] of connectionString) {
  connection[prop.split(' ')[0]] = value;
}
```